# How come code I used to read file from website works in java but not android emulator?

Tags: java, android-emulator, urlconnection

The below code works for giving me the text "brendan's android" when I test the code in a regular .java with eclipse but throws me an error exception when I run it in the main activity for the android emulator.

I have tried using HttpURLConnection instead of URLConnection and that did not fix the problem.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        String urlStr = "http://www.brendan-weinstein.com/android.html";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection conn = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String testline = rd.readLine();
        Toast.makeText(GenForm.this, testline, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        rd.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(GenForm.this, "reader did not work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you paste the exception? What kind of exception is it?

Random guess: did you add the need for internet permissions to your manifest?
edit:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Ah!  That was it!  Thanks so much.  How would I go about finding the type of error it is in the android emulator.  In Java I usually use e.printStackTrace()

Comment: Sorry, missed your question, but you could get the info from the 'ex' object: ex.getMessage() from the top of my head, or otherwise ex.toString() should work.

Comment: and, ofcourse, you could vote the answer 'accepted' if you're thus inclined ;)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  Still getting used to this incredibly useful website!  Thanks for the help!